# iOS: How to retrieve the date when an app was purchased?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to retrieve from Apple the date when my app was purchased by a customer? I need this date for not making charge with in-app purchases.

Comment: This can be done in iOS 7 and later by retrieving and processing the app receipt. See the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982806/ios-app-purchase-date

Comment: @RachelGallen That other question is old. As of iOS 7 it can be done.

Comment: @rmaddy not everyone is on the ios 7 platform yet

Comment: I am on. Does it return exact date like 2011/9/17?

Comment: Read the document I referenced.

Comment: Yes I do it right now.